# Does C# have a way of creating an alias of a local variable?

Tags: c#, .net

I know this seems trivial and the compiler may make the optimization anyways, but let's say I have a piece of code like

```
for (i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str[str.Length - i]);

}
```

and I want to write it like

```
for (int i = 0, n = str.Length; i < n; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str[n - i]);
}
```

but I don't want the extra memory from the copy `n = str.Length`. Is there some way I can simply say that `n` points to `str.Length` without creating any extra memory?

Comment: It needs to be stored somewhere in memory. In this case the length is an integer so even if you used a pointer, the pointer will take the same amount of space. Btw in both versions you will get index out of range exception.

Comment: Yes you can declare and unsafe block (enable it in project setting beforehand) and then create a pointer. But, for your own information we are not living in 80s anymore, and this tiny bit of extra memory allocation will do you no harm.

Comment: I think he means something like a preprocessor define.

Comment: If you can't afford an `int` allocation you have no business writing in .net.

Comment: What is your target hardware where one temporary int variable would make any difference? Toasters?

Comment: @Rotem: Excellent comment.

Comment: Guys, the int might just be an example...

Comment: @oliver A better example would be a huge `struct` rather than an `int`, which in itself would be a bad design.

Comment: I think this is just a hypothetical example and the OP is asking due to being curious. I doubt he actually wants to optimise a piece of code.

Comment: @user7127000: what you want to do is an example of premature optimization. Just assign it to an ordinary variable and the compiler will do its job extremely well.

Comment: Adding an item to a List<> does not duplicate the data.  For example : string a = "apple"; b = "banana"; c = "cherry"; List<string> fruit = new List<string>() { a, b, c};  fruit contains pointers to the original array a, b,c.

Comment: @jdweng How is that relevant?

Comment: You most likely don't have any choice in the matter. The compiler (either C# or JIT) will probably hoist the loop invariant out of the loop and into a local variable anyway.

Comment: @AlexC. How is that related?

Comment: The list object is an alias and does not copy the data just like the OP asked.

Comment: @Rotem :( Upon further reading, I might have been mistaken

Comment: @Rotem is there a way for me to remove the flag?

Comment: It's not just an 'extra allocation', introducing the `n` in the for loop might unsettle an important optimization. So I would start with questioning the 'cosmetic' requirement here. Just keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, and it allows you to point multiple pointers to the reference of a single primitive value type. This accordingly prevents the object from the being cloned (it's value being copied and assigned).

```
unsafe{
   int targetValue = 200;
   int* ptr1 = &targetValue;
   int* ptr2 = &targetValue;
   targetValue = 400;
   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", *ptr1, *ptr2);
}
```

The output will be `400 400`.

Comment: Of course you just allocated a 4/8-byte pointer to avoid allocating a 4-byte `int`.

Comment: @Rotem: That's right, but I think this is the closest answer to the question, as the title asks for creating delegates for local variables.

Comment: @Transcendent: no criticism about the quality of your answer, but I highly doubt that the OP will replace his simple code by something that complicated. It's close to code abuse.

Comment: @oliver: I agree with you. The point was just to prove that in C# you can create delegates for local variables as I mentioned.

Comment: You don't need `unsafe` for this - in recent versions of C# you can use "ref locals": `ref int n = ref targetValue;` - job done

Comment: @MarcGravell: First time hearing about that. That would be amazing. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @Transcendent that's in C# 7.0 and above